# Alerting based on value in log entry written every 20 minutes

Tags: alert, threshold, stackdriver

I need to create an alert that seems pretty simple, but am having a hard time figuring out the threshold and the duration needed for the alert to fire.

We have a process that writes a value into the log every 20 minutes. The entry includes a "count" value, and if we get two entries in a row with a count value of zero, then we want an alert to fire.

My first try was a threshold of "above 1" for 20 minutes but that didn't fire. So now I'm trying "above 0" for "most recent value". Or it may be somewhere in between...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Can you elaborate your use case a bit more providing a screenshot of your alert configuration? Are you trying to follow [this document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts#creating_a_simple_alerting_policy_on_a_counter_metric) for creating a policy on a counter matric?

Answer (score 1):

The threshold value in the alert condition UI is the per-second rate. If you have 2 matching log entries in a given minute, the rate will be 2/60 ~= 0.033. A threshold condition of "greater than 0.02 for most recent value" should work for your case.